# How to generalize third party dependency package version with a RPM spec file?

Tags: rpm

I distribute my product as an RPM, and would like to use `Requires` tag for dependencies enforcement.

How do I generalize the dependency package version, in order to support different OS versions my users might have (which affects the dependency package build)?

For example, **openssl** packages might be one of the following, depends on the user `CentOS` version:

```
openssl-0.9.8e-31.el5_11.<arch>.rpm (CentOS-5.11)
openssl-1.0.1e-30.el6_6.2.<arch>.rpm (CentOS-6.6)
openssl-1.0.1e-34.el7_0.6.<arch>.rpm (CentOS-7.0.1406)
```

Comment: Hi Tomper. I see you often 'tag' your titles using a bar separator. The Stack Overflow community has [discussed this format](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/253076), and on balance tends to favour questions as sentences, rather than with various bar/colon/bracket tagging hacks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Requires: openssl` will cause your package to have an unspecific `openssl` requirement.

That, however, will not help you if your package links against the openssl libraries (as opposed to just using the `openssl` command line tool, etc.) because `rpm` will pick up the shared library dependencies itself and include them (by version/etc.) in the requirements of your package.

You can turn that off by disabling automatic requirements processing (but in CentOS 5 that is an all-or-nothing proposition) but that still won't help anything actually *run* on all the CentOS versions. For that you'd need to include three different versions of the library/binary. One each that links against each version of openssl from each version of CentOS (though possibly just one for CentOS 6 and CentOS 7 since they are both on `1.0.1`).